# Neo4j recover corrupt nodes

Tags: neo4j, upgrade, corruption

I just upgraded neo4j from 2.0.3 to 2.1.1 via the debian repository.

After restarting (setting `allow_store_upgrade=true`) I noticed an issue with one of the nodes :

```
Unable to load one or more relationships from Node[324720]. This usually happens when relationships are deleted by someone else just as we are about to load them. Please try again.
```

This node was updated right before shutting down the database. Maybe that could be the cause?

Anyway, I don't see any errors in `messages.log`.

Furthermore, now, when I try to backup the database :

```
Performing backup from 'single://10.90.169.86'
19:29:04.480 [main] INFO  o.n.k.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase - No locking implementation specified, defaulting to 'forseti'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /mnt/backup/neo4j-backup
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:357)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:90)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:199)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupService.startTemporaryDb(BackupService.java:287)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupService.doIncrementalBackup(BackupService.java:203)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupService.doIncrementalBackupOrFallbackToFull(BackupService.java:231)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupTool.doBackup(BackupTool.java:235)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupTool.run(BackupTool.java:162)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupTool.main(BackupTool.java:72)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@10b434b' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:334)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@597e83fc' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:164)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException: Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true"
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.ConfigMapUpgradeConfiguration.checkConfigurationAllowsAutomaticUpgrade(ConfigMapUpgradeConfiguration.java:39)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:139)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:350)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    ... 14 more
```

Of course I tried setting `allow_store_upgrade` and restarting, but it does not change anything.

Is there a way to fix this ? I'm not sure what other information you need (logs, etc.), so let me know.

Comment: It would be great if you could send us your store-files, perhaps you can make them available via dropbox and send the link to michael at neotechnology.com Thanks so much. Please check that the original data is still there in an `upgrade_backup` (or similar) directory.

Comment: @MichaelHunger I'm going to send you the files, thank you. Yes, the original data is there.

Comment: @MichaelHunger, I sent you an e-mail. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I did not manage to fix this issue yet. I cannot even delete the node so I'm running out of options :-/

Comment: Does using Neo4j 2.1.2 solve your problem?

Comment: The changelog of 2.1.2 seems to fix this issue. I'll let you know asap!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to upgrade our 2.0.4 store to 2.1.4 in HA mode. Turned out that you should upgrade in SINGLE mode and then restart in HA mode again. But before doing that the slaves should be emptied so it synchronizes automatically.

The details are in the manual: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.1.4/ha-upgrade-guide.html#ha-standard-upgrade